# Changing Deployment Target In motion-game

Tags: ios, ruby, rubymotion, motion-game

I'm new to the development world and have just started to develop an app using motion-game along with RubyMotion (free version).

I've built a RubyMotion project using the motion-game template but when I build the project using rake ios:simulator, I get the following message:

```
ERROR! Deployment target 7.0 is not supported by this version of RubyMotion
```

I thought I would just be able to specify the deployment target in the config/ios.rb setup file like so:

```
Motion::Project::App.setup do |app|
   # Use `rake ios:config' to see complete project settings.
   app.name = 'hello'
   app.deployment_target = '11.2'
end
```

But when I build the project, I still get the same ERROR! message. What am I missing?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like dependency issue and/or config.  Did you try to run `rake ios:config` and paste the output here?

Comment: Hi @lacostenycoder. I get the same ERROR! message as posted above when I do `rake ios:config`.

Comment: Is the the full trace message or is there more output in the error?

Comment: The ERROR! message is all I get back. There's nothing else shown from the output.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much activity going on with motion-game within the RubyMotion community. May look to use other technologies instead.